# Random number generator C

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

I can't seem to figure out why this is not working. I am trying to get these two void functions to generate randoms numbers when called in the main. I think the problem has to do with `srand(time(NULL));` in the void function's. I think that when it gets called in the main and runs in the for loop, `srand(time(NULL));` is not updated so it prints out the same number x times. numGen_10 should generate 1-10 and numGen_4 should generate 1-4 based on a variable.

What can I do to get the functions to output different random numbers each time the function is called?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void numGen_10(int xOry, int* xRey);
void numGen_4(int num, int choice, int *choiceRe);


int main()
{
    int x;
    int num = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        numGen_10(x, &x);
        printf("val : %d \n", x);
    }

    printf("------------------------\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        numGen_4(4, x, &x);
        printf("val2 : %d \n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}



void numGen_10(int xOry, int *xRey)
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand() % 10 + 1;
        xOry = r;
        *xRey = xOry;
    return;
}

void numGen_4(int num, int choice, int *choiceRe)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    choice = rand() % num + 1;
    *choiceRe = choice;
    return;
}
```

Comment: `srand` should only be called once in the entire run of the program. Call it as the first executable statement in main.

Comment: @ooga: You should probably add that as an answer! :)

Comment: @Baldrick I'm sure it's been answered many times!.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-only-once/7343909#7343909

Comment: @ooga  Oh... You only call it once?

Comment: @T.Malo That's what you want in your case. By calling it before each `rand` call, and calling it in a tight loop, you end up re-seeding the RNG each time with exactly the same number (since `time` usually only returns seconds), giving you the same result over and over.

Comment: Wow did not know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/?kw=srand) for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random number generator is completely deterministic; it will always output the same sequence of numbers for any given seed.  `srand()` seeds the random number generator.  So by calling `srand()` with the time immediately before each call to `rand()`, and since your loops will take less than a second to execute, you'll always get the same random number (or maybe two if the time happens to change in the middle).

Try calling `srand()` once before entering the loops.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for fun* , add a delay of 1 second before each `srand` call when calling `srand` multiple times :

```
    sleep(1);
    /* or delay(1001); or usleep(500000);usleep(500000); based on availability */
    srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: Do you mean 60 iteration loop will take 1 minute to execute the program of few Micro-seconds ?

Comment: What library includes delay?

Comment: @T.Malo If delay is not available , try `sleep(1);` or `usleep(1000000);` as said just for fun ! Both worked for me . My goodness , I compiled a c program after 10+ years .

Comment: Haha I gather that the industry does not use C but school really wants you to know it. Java, C++, and other higher level seem like what you should really know.

Comment: @T.Malo I'm in industry, and coding in `C` is 60% of the work I do for the company.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to what others said about solving problem of `srand` I would like to add a remark about how you use pointers, calling your functions with `x` and `&x` is pointless, you can just call either with pointer only or with variable only:

*calling with pointer :*

```
void numGen_10(int* xRey); // prototype
void numGen_10(int *xRey) // function's body
{
    int r = rand() % 10 + 1;
    *xRey = r; 
    return;
}
numGen_4(4, &x); // use from the main function
```

*calling with variable :*

```
int numGen_10(int xRey); // prototype
int numGen_10(int xRey) //function's body 
{
    int r = rand() % 10 + 1;
    return r;
}
int y = numGen_4(4, x);  // use from the main function
```